# ng-click does nothing (todo list example)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to play around with some test in angular. but failed to add item in a todo list app sample:

```
app.controller('MainControl', function($scope){

$scope.tasks = [
    {
    "name":"task 1",
    },

    {"name":"task 2",
    }
];

    var addTask = function(){
        $scope.tasks.push({
            "name": $scope.input,
        });
        $scope.input = "";
    };
});
```

I wonder why it doesn't work, no error in the console.

my html

```
  <body ng-controller="MainControl">
    <div>
      <label>I want to:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="input">
      <button ng-click="addTask()">Add</button>
    </div>

    <div>
      <ul ng-repeat="task in tasks">
      <li>{{task.name}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addTask` must be a `$scope` property, i.e. `$scope.addTask = function() {}` instead of `var addTask = function() {}`.

**Edit after comments:**

```
<form ng-submit="addTask()">
    <label>I want to:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="input">
    <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

Comment: nice answer! and do you know how to catch enter key press? I tried ng-submit but it doesn't work. I want the button to be clickable and support enter key press.

Comment: @user3398172 You could put your label/input/button in a `form` tag, use `ng-submit` on that form tag with your function as value, and remove the ng-click and add `type="submit"` to your button. I edited my answer ;)